# Understanding the calibration of High-frequency trading in a limit order book

Tags: backtesting, simulations, market-making, limit-order-book, stochastic-control

I am trying understand and replicate this [thesis](https://pure.manchester.ac.uk/ws/portalfiles/portal/208486475/FULL_TEXT.PDF), which is based on, *High-frequency trading in a limit order book* by [(Avellaneda and Stoikov, 2008)](https://math.nyu.edu/%7Eavellane/HighFrequencyTrading.pdf) and *Optimal market making*, by [Olivier Gueant, 2017](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.01862.pdf), except the thesis uses real historical data to calculate the intensities and uses best bid(ask) as the reference price when calculating the intensities $\lambda^a$($\lambda^b$), whilst Avellaneda uses the mid-price.

I currently have a full-day, 10 level limit order book with $0.1$ second increments. I also have the order info such as hidden order, cancellation, MO buy/sell, LO placed etc with the same increments in-sync.

Therefore, I can calculate intensities $\lambda_t = \Lambda(\delta_t)$, and solve for $A$ and $k$ in $\Lambda(\delta_t)=Ae^{-k\delta}$, during the time period of the LOB data. As well as the $\sigma$ (assuming constant volatility for now).

**Main question:** How is the back-test actually conducted?

From what I understand, the bid and ask price are simulated using:

$$\begin{align} dS_t^b  & = \sigma S_t^bdW_t^b \\  dS_t^a  & = \sigma S_t^a dW_t^a \end{align}$$

and $$\begin{align} \delta_t^b & = S_t - S_t^b \\ \delta_t^a & = S_t^a - S_t,\end{align}$$

where $S_t$ is the reference price.

And the MM cash account is modelled by:

$$
d X_t=\left(S_t+\delta^a\right) d N_t^a-\left(S_t-\delta^b\right) d N_t^b
$$

where $N_t$ is a poisson distribution with the intensity $\lambda_t$, which is calculated from the historical dataset I have.

My confusion lies in their algorithm and simulation. If they simulate the ask and bid price, it obviously won’t follow the fluctuations of the bid-ask spread in the dataset. I.e. if $S_0 = 100$ and $S_3 = 80$ from the simulation, but what if the level 1 bid-ask price is $S_3=101$ and $S_3=103$?

From algorithm 1 on page 74 of the thesis, it seems that they calculate $\delta^a$ and $\delta^b$ at $t=0$, with starting buy and sell positions in the order book of $LO^a$ and $LO^b$. Then they simulate $S_t^a$ and $S_t^b$ and if the simulated bid-asks meet their orders, then it’s executed.

I am not sure how this simulation process is happening. And if we are simulating, $S_t^a$ and $S_t^b$, what happens if $S_t^a<S_t^b$?

Whilst in the Avellaneda and Stoikov paper, they only simulate the mid-price and then use the intensities as to whether the MM wealth changes.

Or is only $d X_t=(S_t+\delta^a) d N_t^a - …$ simulated using the parameters we calculated from the historical LOB data?

Some insights would be greatly appreciated.